# Is it possible to order or purchase a hardcopy of an NTSB report?

Tags: ntsb

I am an independent researcher working closely with several NTSB aviation accident reports and would prefer a printed hard-copy. I realize I can print out all of the relevant sections of each report but was curious as to whether hard-copies are published by NTSB?

*Edit: I am working on a museum display which would include the presentation of a hard-copy of a report. The specific packaging by NTSB would be valuable to me in this context.

Comment: Contact the NTSB...

Comment: You can get them from sellers on Amazon book-on-demand. Which reports do you need? Give me a day to upload them to Amazon book-on-demand... ;) ;)  J/K take the PDF on a USB stick down to Kinkos or other competent copy shop, and they'll print it out and bind it for you.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'm not sure that this is on topic, but the short answer seems to be that you need to contact the [National Technical Information Service](https://www.ntis.gov/). NTSB reports *used to* include this text:

> Accident reports, safety studies, special investigation reports,
> statistical reviews, and safety recommendations may be downloaded from
> the NTSB Web site, or printed copies may be purchased from:
>
> **National Technical Information Service**
> 5285 Port Royal Road   Springfield, Virginia 22161
>
> (703) 487-4630 (Subscription Orders)   (703) 487-4650 (Single-Copy
> Orders)
> *(Subscription rates apply to certain recurring publications)*

The current wording is:

> Copies of NTSB publications may be downloaded at no cost from the
> National Technical Information Service, at the National Technical
> Reports Library search page, using product number PB2020-101001. For
> additional assistance, contact—
> **National Technical Information Service
>
> 5301 Shawnee Rd.
>
> Alexandria, VA 22312
> (800) 553-6847 or (703) 605-6000**

Alternatively, since NTSB reports [are in the public domain](https://www.ntsb.gov/about/Policies/Pages/Policies.aspx) (with some limited caveats) you could just get them printed at your local print store, presumably much more quickly and cheaply than by going to NTIS.

Answer (score 6):

Are you looking for the big ones with titles with "NTSB/AAR[yr]-[number]" in them (as opposed to the shorter, automatically-generated reports you get by browsing around in [the NTSB's aviation accident database](https://www.ntsb.gov/_layouts/ntsb.aviation/index.aspx)?

If so, most of them can be downloaded in PDF format [from the NTSB website](https://www.ntsb.gov/investigations/AccidentReports/Pages/aviation.aspx), free of charge, although some of the reports listed (especially the older ones) don't have an online copy available there.  Alternatively, Embry-Riddle Aeronautical University's Hunt Library holds their own copies of every NTSB/AAR[yr]-[number]-series report that has been published, [and has PDFs available on their website for every single one](https://huntlibrary.erau.edu/collections/aerospace-and-aviation-reports/ntsb/aircraft-accident-reports), also *gratis*.

Comment: The Embry-Riddle connection is valuable, but it sounds like the questioner already knows how to download PDFs.  For whatever reason, the question is about something else.